# Getting console forEach of undefined error with vue.js v-for functionality and axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am attempting to load calendar events from an API and then display them using `Axios` and `Vue.js`. It is working, but I am getting the following error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'forEach' of undefined"

My vue file is below. The content renders fine but every time the site loads the above warning shows up. Must be something simple I am missing.

```html
<template>
    <div class="row row-equal">
      <div class="flex xs12">
        <va-card
          no-padding-h
          style="overflow-x: auto;"
          :title=title>
          <va-timeline style="min-width: 400px;" v-if="meetings">
              <va-timeline-item v-for="event in meetings">
                <template slot="before">
                  <div
                    class="title text--center"
                    :style="{color: $themes.success}">
                    {{ event.start }} - {{ event.end }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="va-timeline-item__description">
                    {{ event.summary }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="va-timeline-item__description">
                    {{ event.creator }}
                  </div>
                </template>
              </va-timeline-item>
          </va-timeline>
        </va-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
var moment = require('moment')
export default {
  name: 'dashboard-calendars',
  props: ['title'],
  data () {
    return {
      meetings: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadCalendars () {
      this.$http.get('calendar?name=' + this.$props.title + '&format=json')
        .then(response => {
          this.meetings = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
        // handle error
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loadCalendars()
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.title {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

</style>
<style>
  .va-card__header-title{
      font-size: 1.0em !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What is the value of `response.data`?

Comment: On the top of my head I would assume Vue is trying to iterate over something `undefined` since at that moment it is still `undefined`, probably linked to the asynchronous http request which of course finishes after the component is rendered & mounted. So maybe a timing issue. Indeed `response.data` would be interesting to know as @T. Short mentioned. Or try using `v-if = "meetings.length > 0"` instead of `v-if = "meetings"` .

Comment: @PascalLamers yep it was as simple as you just stated. Since the object was created v-if='meeting' Vue was still getting in the v-for and tried to access an undefined object. Simply adding that meetings.length > 0 did it.

Answer (score 1):

The v-for was still being executed as the v-if='meetings' was allowing the loop to continue so using @pascalLamers response I added the length check and that worked.

````
              <va-timeline-item v-for="event in meetings">
                <template slot="before">
                  <div
                    class="title text--center"
                    :style="{color: $themes.success}">
                    {{ event.start }} - {{ event.end }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="va-timeline-item__description">
                    {{ event.summary }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="va-timeline-item__description">
                    {{ event.creator }}
                  </div>
                </template>
              </va-timeline-item>
          </va-timeline>```
````

Comment: Great ! Glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way, put it in the created lifecycle hook and make it async:

```
var moment = require('moment')
export default {
   name: 'dashboard-calendars',
   props: ['title'],
   data () {
      return {
         meetings: [],
      }
   },
   async created() {

     await this.$http.get('calendar?name=' + this.$props.title + '&format=json')
    .then(response => {
      this.meetings = response.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
    // handle error
      console.log(error)
    })

},
}
```